# errors installing ascii-video globally, problems with lwip

Tags: npm-install, lwip

Trying to install [`ascii-video`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ascii-video), using command `npm i ascii-video -g` I encountered the following problem:

```less
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.10.0/lib/node_modules/ascii- 
video/node_modules/lwip2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! Installing lwip. If this fails, just install GraphicsMagick 
(http://www.graphicsmagick.org/).
npm ERR! It seems like lwip failed to be intalled. Please check the errors.
```

followed by errors from compiling some C++ source. What should I do? Install `lwip` or GraphicsMagick? I'm on Pop OS Linux.